# “Musical teeth?” What on Earth does she mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

I just received this rather baffling pair of sentences in correspondence:

> Tenors are usually like hens' teeth and about as musical. We think your teeth are more musical than that!

The context is that I regrettably had to call in my absence due to having taken ill. I *think* it is meant in a positive sense, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: *Hen's teeth* is an idiom meaning either *vanishingly rare* or *nonexistent* (because hen don't have teeth)z she's saying it's hard to find tenors, and even harder to find ones with (musical talent). Because you are tenor with musical talent, she regrets your absence, and wants you back for the next performance or practice or whatever.

Comment: So, with that solved, we might want to discuss your partial capitalisation of the word 'Earth' in your question...

Comment: @DanBron how long did it take to compose that comment? The same time it would have taken to post it as an answer. Or refrain from giving answers in comments  within three minutes of a question being posted, or write an answer!

Comment: @Keepthesemind Yeah, I know, idioms usually leave the earth non-capitalised. I just think it makes more sense with a capital E, as I am referring to the planet, not soil.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How long did it take you to type *your* comment? In the same time you could have written your own answer, based on mine or not. [Don't be a hypocrite](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/what-to-do-with-those-questions-which-have-received-answers-in-comments/9922#comment39556_9922). It takes more effort to write an answer, because we have to elaborate, add sources, and generally flesh it out. If you want to put in the extra effort go ahead, but don't make demands of me. As you said, my way, *OP got an answer to his question in 3 minutes*.

Comment: @DanBron I'm a hypocrite? Fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think questions like this should be off-topic "What does this email I got mean?" are as useful as proofreading.

Comment: @Mitch unsurprisingly, the OP focused on the meaning of "musical teeth", which as far as I know, is pretty meaningless, a "musical ear" is OK, a musical talent, idem but "teeth"? It's a legit question, although there are no  signs of research, so you could argue that the Q is still off-topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, there's a lot weird in that sentence that might be confusing and need explanation (hen's teeth is an expression, teeth later used non-literally). Frankly, I think there needs to be a place for that kind of question, but ELU is not an explanation service any more than it is a proofreading service or song meaning service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding upon Dan Bron's comment:

> *Hen's teeth* is an idiom meaning either vanishingly rare or nonexistent (because birds don't have teeth).
>
> She's saying it's hard to find tenors, and even harder to find ones with (musical) talent. Because you are tenor with musical talent, she regrets your absence, and wants you back for the next performance or practice or whatever.

See: ***Scarce as hen's teeth*** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scarce-as-hen-s-teeth)

> *"On a rainy night, taxis are as scarce as hen's teeth."*

Comment: Why would a CW answer be downvoted is beyond me, the question is not off topic, and the comment got 7 upvotes. Tsk... users, who understands 'em?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The downvoter forgot to take his meds

Comment: I know what the idiom *hen's teeth* mean. I just found the rest of it baffling. If you're sure there's nothing more to it, though, I'll accept this answer.